# SolidJS directives with use:___ throw errors for typescript in JSX

Tags: typescript, solid-js

I am converting this forms example that is in JS into TS:
https://www.solidjs.com/examples/forms

In doing so, I am encountering a typescript error relating to the directives in html:
[image]

It seems that typescript is marking validate and formSubmit as unused variables, and in the jsx code, it is throwing the error:

```
Property 'use:formSubmit' does not exist on type 'FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend built-in JSX types first:

```
declare module "solid-js" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Directives {}
  }
}
```

Then make sure directive is not stripped off by Typescript:

```js
true && formSubmit
```

This is important because you may suppress the type error using a pragma, it will not prevent the directive from being tree-shaken. You can test this by exporting the directive into a separate module. Without the line above, directive will not be included in the compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

In the directives documentation for SolidJS:

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#use___

It gives the example for a directive called model:

```
<input type="text" use:model={[name, setName]} />;
```

```
declare module "solid-js" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Directives {
      model: [() => any, (v: any) => any];
    }
  }
}
```

By adding this before the component:

```
type ValidationFunction = ({ value }: { value: string; }) => Promise<unknown>;

declare module "solid-js" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Directives {
      formSubmit: (form: HTMLFormElement) => void;
      validate: ValidationFunction[];
    }
  }
}
```

This gets rid of the jsx errors.

However, the directive names still throw the error:

```
formSubmit is declared but its value is never read.
```

Even though it is used as a directive in the jsx.

To resolve this:

```
// @ts-ignore
const { validate, formSubmit, errors } = useForm({
```

Or you can do to make it show up as a used variable:

```
true && formSubmit
```

Comment: Where should we extend the solid-js types? When I add the snippet to a `directive.d.ts` file I get error for other imports from solid-js `Module solid-js has no exported member createMemo`